# Raspberry Pi V4 PYTON, MYSQL, disconnect from outside internet

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have this weird problem.

I live in a townhouse, sort of like an apartment complex where I rent the unit. I am unable to physically edit the lock hardware of the house, so I decided to use a raspberry pi and a servo along with an RFID sensor, some notification LED lights, a buzzer, a door open/close sensor, etc...

I also have another raspberry pi running a webserver, MySQL database, and chromium with an attatched pi 7 inch display mounted to my wall.

The raspberry pi 4, 4gb ram is mounted on the door connects to a RFID chip (located outside the door), verification LEDS (red/green) (located outside the door), doorbell (located outside the door), door open/close sensor (located inside the door), servo (to control lock) (located inside the door). This pi runs a python script with 5 threads, and 1 additional process. Its operating system is RASPBIAN lite.

Thread 1 runs my godaddy DDNS updater so that my domain can be updated therefor my dynamic ISP IP can be updated every 30 minutes. It just time.sleeps(30minsinseconds) then re-checks if the ip changed and if so it updates the godaddy domain.

Thread 2 This is my emergency button (just in case for whatever reason I cannot connect to raspberry pi 3 MySQL database, I can still get out my door). This just checks if the button on the door mounted thing was pressed if so, unlock or lock depending on a variable set within-script

Thread 3 This is my door status updating script. This script runs a query to the raspberry pi 3 (on a MySQL connection that reconnects every 3 hours) every half a second (500milliseconds, .5/second). The way this works is just using time.sleep(.5). Yes I know that due to system delays it may not be .5/s which is perfectly fine with me. This is the thread I think that's causing problems...

Thread 4 This is my thread that locks the door every 2.5 hours. It just servo_lock() then time.sleep(2.5hoursinseconds). This is for if my door forgets to be locked (yeah I don't usually have this problem but I am a safe ass)

Thread 5 This is my doorbell button. Once detected it was pressed it sleeps for .15 seconds and checks again. This helps prevent invalid button presses. If the button was still pressed, it then shoots a text to my phone using Twillo, "Ding Dong, your doorbell has been pressed. Please answer the door."

Thread 6 (Not setup yet). Will detect if the door has been opened for 1 second or greater and if so, it will check if the alarm I can have set on the mysql database and alarm using the buzzer if so.

Process 2 (apart from the main python script..) is my RFID sensor. Unfortunately to get this to work I have to use another process over a thread. For whatever reason the raspberry pi small rfid sensor mfc522 or whatever it is does not allow me to make an additional thread and run it (haven't figured that one out, but regardless another process within the same python script works just fine.)

The Raspberry pi 3 b+ is mounted to the wall with a case that supports tilting the display and putting the 7 inch original pi display inside the case. This pi only holds the database, and web-server.

Now the main problem: After about a day or so, raspberry pi 4 located on a reserved IP address (192.168.0.13) and my raspberry pi 3b+ located on (192.168.0.14) become INACCESSABLE to anybody else on the inner router network. Ping does not work, I cannot arp -a mapping out all devices on my network. I just simply cannot find it.

I see the "connected devices" in the routers web API and I see their reserved IP is still what I set them, but I don't seem to be able to connect to them over my desktop computer located on ip (192.168.0.100). Whenever I ping, it just resolves my own IP address.

The strangest part I find is Raspberry Pi 3 which is only displaying the website from itself with a "lock" and "unlock" button on the webpage that only updates a database value (which is stored on itself) can still trigger the raspberry pi 4 to unlock or lock when thread 3 on it detects the different database value.

I would like to know why my router prevents access or the servers prevent access to themselves after so long. Is it due to consistent (500ms) thread 3 connection. Is it because my router is junk (Its a spectrum modem/router (Technicolor brand), I wouldn't be surprised). Also, if they disconnect from the router how come they are still connected to each other???.

One last note. One is on 5ghz band WIFI, one is on 2.4ghz WIFI. Idk why I set it up like that, I just did.. (Oh.. and I probably didn't mention they were on WIFI too... lol

Thanks for any help! Also, if you can think of any better way to process things let me know :)

Comment: Strangely enough, just after posting this, arp -a on my 192.168.0.100 device now detects the two raspberry pi's and I can connect to them. I did not restart my router, nor did I restart the devices. I might've experienced that once but most of the time they just aren't accessible anymore. The only thing I did differently I think was loading my router webpage

Comment: A kind update, my wall mounted pi was running chromium which was infinite looping without a delay to get a dynamic string from doorstatusupsate.php with java ajax this was causing this pis CPU to sky-rocket into the 2.50 load range. Ive set a delay and now the load stays under .50.

Comment: Another kind update, my raspberry pi 4 with all the buttons and servo had a cpu usage of 2.5 as well, I come to the conclusion to add time.sleep(.1) to my doorbell button and inside saftey button. This reduced CPU usage to a solid .90-1.20. One process (the rfid sensor) unfortunately runs in an infinite while loop through its github backbone code I installed w (sudo pip3 install mfrc522). With that said I could upgrade to a better system there but I dont feel like rewiring. Well see if the button update helps the pi continue to allow an ssh connection :)

Comment: With the previous updates, I've learned that the display no longer disconnects as the load is only at 1.00-1.20 and its never consistently using 100% of a CPU core. My door model still disconnects but once you try to connect, and give it 10 minutes, I can then make an ssh connection to it after that. It is using 100% of one of the CPU cores for the while True: statement for the RFID reader. I will see if I cant fix that issue.

Comment: Was able to drastically decrease CPU usage of the door controller raspberry pi by forcing the RFID sensor to sleep for .01 of a second. I still have problems with disconnect from that raspberry pi. Still unsure why. The wall mounted pi controlling the web interface seems to be stable at keeping a connection now.